# Weak randomness relative to finite-state machines

Tags: computation, algorithmic-randomness

Is there a nice example of a sequence that looks random to any predictor whose predictions use a finite-state machine?

More precisely, consider a finite-state machine $M$ with input alphabet {0,1} and output alphabet {0,1}; each time it reads a new bit in its input stream, it updates its state and writes a new bit to its output stream (which should be interpreted as its prediction of the value of the next input bit). We seek a sequence of bits such that no matter what machine $M$ reads it, the input and output streams of $M$ agree asymptotically half the time. Such a sequence cannot be created by any finite-state mechanism (i.e. cannot be preperiodic), but perhaps it can be generated using a model of computation only slightly stronger.

Also, are there extant theories of weakened randomness relative to very limited models of computation?

Comment: In relation to “but perhaps it can be generated using a model of computation only slightly stronger”, at least, we know that it can be generated in general (using a Turing Machine). As clearly stated in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Connection_to_finite-state_machines): “normal sequences are precisely those that appear random to any finite-state machine”. Thus, in fact we need any computable normal number (e.g. Veronica Becher and Santiago Figueira. An example of a computable absolutely normal number. Theoretical Computer Science, 270:947–958, 2002).